# is there a way to slide more tabs into view using jquery UI tabs?

Tags: jquery, tabs, pagination, sliding

i am using jquery UI tabs.  works great.  i have right now 5 tabs using a fixed width.  i will be adding more tabs but i don't want to grow the width any more.  so what i want to provide is  way to click on a "more" type link and display the next "page" of tabs.  it would be cool if i could have the next set of tabs "slide" into view.  note i'm only talking about the tabs themselves, not the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only plugin i have found about this is http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-tabs-paging/

But they do it with pages .. so each time you press the button for the next tabs it will bring the next page of tabs that fit..  have a look ..

Comment: @mike, glad it fits your needs :)